# jqGrid 4.13.0 error with IE8 Object.create

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, internet-explorer-8, compatibility, free-jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid 4.13.0 and it seems to cause an error when using IE8. The error is localized in the `jquery.fmatter` module.

The `YesObject` and `NoObject` use `Object.create` which is not IE8 compatible. Any idea for a workaround ? Many thanks.

```
var fmatter = $.fmatter,
    getOptionByName = function (colModel, name) {
        ...
    },
    parseCheckboxOptions = function (options) {
        ...
    },
    YesObject = Object.create(null, {
        1: { value: 1 },
        x: { value: 1 },
        "true": { value: 1 },
        yes: { value: 1 },
        on: { value: 1 }
    }),
    NoObject = Object.create(null, {
        0: { value: 1 },
        "false": { value: 1 },
        no: { value: 1 },
        off: { value: 1 }
    });
```

Comment: Do you have to support ie8? there is not a lot of grid functionality out there that supports ie8 anymore...

Comment: I do want to support IE8, but I don't have any computer with IE8 for testing. I'll post the fix to GitHub and will ask you to make the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for the bug report! I have technical problems to test free jqGrid on IE8, but I don't want to drop support it till it will be really required.

The reason of the strange usage of `Object.create` was [the test](http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-indexof-vs-in/12), which shows how one can better test the existence of element in array. On my tests with all modern web browsers the way with `Object.create` was better and I've chosen it initially.

I committed [the bug fix](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/640cde1529b8f7211caac69c806a83735a4dd708) to GitHub. Please get the latest source from [the repository](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid).

Comment: @jfprevot: You are welcome! I'll plan to publish 4.13.1, which include the fix and some other changes, at the end of the week.